# Vulkan abort problematic commands?

Tags: graphics, 3d, vulkan

I have an application where multiple threads would be rendering different parts of a world. However it may occur that one of those threads could submit a highly problematic, or even malicious, command to Vulkan.

Is there anyway to preemptively check for issues with the command that could catch it being problematic? Or let it attempt to be executed, but then by some means determine if it is problematic and abort it? All the while not corrupting or wrecking appropriate commands that were submitted from other threads.

I know obvious solution is "don't submit malicious commands!" but without explaining everything, the jist of this is to try and create a kind graphics sandbox.

Comment: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers

Comment: "*However it may occur that one of those threads could submit a highly problematic, or even malicious, command to Vulkan.*" But those threads are *yours*. Either you wrote them or you're allowing someone else to write them.

Answer (score 1):

The Vulkan run-time assumes well formed input; there isn't any error checking (that's left to layer drivers) so without validation you could get rendering corruption or driver crashes.

You can get some limited protection to GPU-side buffer overruns using `robustBufferAccess`, but it only catches a tiny subset of the problems.

Beyond that the only real solution is to rely on host process isolation, and put each content provider into a separate process on the host OS with a unique rendering context.

Even with that you can get trivial denial-of-service (shader with a very long running and/or infinite loop), which the API doesn't really give you any means to control. You'd be reliant on the privileged GPU driver timing out the process and killing it.

Comment: Is there any way to pre-emptively scan shaders for infinite loops or other such issues?

Comment: For some classes of loop, sure. You have the SPIR-V, so you can parse it and build an AST to analyze, which works for static loop counts. It won't work if you have any data-dependent loops though (e.g. loop limit read from texture or read from buffer).

Comment: Also "infinite" could just be "very very slow".